# Get file content from URL returned old content

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

I read a text file content from an URL and it is working perfectly like below:

```
response = await http.get('http://example.com/complex.txt'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    complex = (convert.json.decode(response.body)['data'] as List)
        .map((e) => Complexes.fromJson(e))
        .toList();

    for (var i in complex) {
      complexes.add(i);
    }
  }
```

But when I change text file content, body of response does not change and show old content.

Questions:

1. Is text caching in host or application?
2. How can I disable this caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with fake parameter like below :

```
response = await http.get('http://example.com/complex.txt?parameter=1'));
```

I do not think it is the best solution but it is solved my problem.